# Iframe error using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, iframe, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following error:

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/share.php?...." class="class">Click me</a>

<div class="modal hide" id="jpmodal">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="loadframe">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('a.class').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var url = $(this).attr('href');
   $("#loadframe").html('<iframe width="300" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="'+url+'"></iframe>');

   $('#jpmodal').modal('toggle');

});
```

The iframe is blank.

Chrome console returns me a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load `http://facebook.com/share.php?...` in an iframe. Facebook blocks it by design to prevent clickjacking.

Using [Send Button - Facebook Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) is a much better option even though it does not support your purpose fully.